# How to update component state from withFormik of Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have `Form` in which I am using `Formik's withFormik` hook. My problem is how can I update loader state from `handleSubmit` function based on that I can show loader.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
.....
.....
<Button
  className={classes.button}
  type="submit"
  color="primary"
  variant="contained"
  disabled={loading}
>
  submit
 {loading && <CircularProgress size={24} className={classes.buttonProgress} />}
</Button>

.......
.......

handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting, setStatus }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
        // submit to the server
        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        setSubmitting(false);
        setStatus(true);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useEffect` and `FormikContextShape` that passed in `FormikContext.Provider` as the value property.

Here is a thorough all in one usage sample code:
https://gist.github.com/tgriesser/fdd08da075fec80328792319606c76e5